# AngularJS service with express error: [$resource:badcfg] object

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-resource

I'm using external mongodb and wrote a node/express server for fetching the data on my localhost.

I query localhost like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/api/bonsais
```

And I'm getting the correct results from my mongodb collection @ mongolab.

```
[{"name":"test,test2","_id":"536be2e2ae54668818000001","__v":0},{"name":"testname","_id":"536fd2df41f84a581c000001","__v":0}]
```

I wrote a service to fetch the data like this:

```
angular.module('bonsaiService', ['ngResource']).
  factory('bonsaiService', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost:8888/api/bonsais',{'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true }});
});
```

I'm getting a Error: [$resource:badcfg] object, which is referring to these [error docs](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/%24resource/badcfg?p0=array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.factory('Bonsai', function($q, $resource){
    var bonsaiResource = $resource('http://localhost:8888/api/bonsais', {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        }
    });

    return {
    get: function() {
      var q = $q.defer();

        bonsaiResource.get({
        },
        function(resp) {
            q.resolve(resp);
        }, function(httpResponse) {
            q.reject(httpResponse);
        });

        return q.promise;
    } };
})
```

try to write it this way.
Then you can call it with Bonsai.get()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @thesearentthedroids, your responds fixed it for me!

Just to follow up, I've used the following to retrieve the data in my controller:

```
bonsaiService.get($scope.trees).then(
    function(data){
        $scope.trees = data;
});
```